# Ordering of Sites on SE Reputation Leaderboards

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

So I was on an aimless stroll through the [SE Leaderboards](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) and <s>planning to usurp the Shog</s> [admiring unicorn points](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta-stackoverflow) when I figured I'd shift to another site to be more productive.

Only my productivity was shot when I saw this:

> [image: Sites Dropdown]

Yes indeed, randomly ordered sites in the horrible Windows default font causing incredible confusion and inability to actually use the menu to migrate. While the main leaderboard site is fine since you can search, this dropdown certainly isn't near as user friendly.

So I was forced to point out this horrible travesty. Please put it in alphabetical order for the dropdown, so that it operates in a manner that anyone sane would expect it to.

<sup>In reality I doubt that feature is used often, if ever, and navigating by typing the first letter of the site name does work, if oddly, so it isn't as if it's something urgent, but yikes that's a badly designed dropdown!</sup>

Comment: Dupe had wrong tags, fixed now. :)