# What is the logic of site order in reputation leagues?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, site-stats

The order of sites on [Reputation Leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) roughly corresponds to their size. However, I could not identify the statistic by which the sites are ordered: it's neither the number of questions, nor the number of users, nor site age... what is it, then?

(In particular, I am curious to know by what measure [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) ranks last in the network.)

---

Not a duplicate of [Ordering of Sites on SE Reputation Leaderboards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217041/;) I am not asking for the order to be changed.

Comment: (Just a guess) Unfortunately, HSM is last in total users, which could be contributing. But the pattern ends there; almost no other sites seem to match in both lists.